# jQuery - cascading classes and on-click functions issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with using jQuery for a pop-up window. I have a class called "clicker".

If you click it the "showHideBox()" function is being called:

```
$(".clicker").click(function(){
    showHideBox();
});
```

`showHideBox` function is showing box -  `$(".box").fadeIn(700)` or hiding it when clicked again -  `$(".box").css("display","none")`.

`.box div` is positioned fixed with high z-index to provide sort of light-box effect.

The `.box div` contains some clickable - interactive bits.

The `.box div` is quite big and it's partially overlapping the `.clicker div`.

the problem is that when you click an area of the .box div which is overlaping the .clicker div the jQuery is acting as if I was clicking  the .clicker.

So it's actually taking listening to the .clicker functionality - even if i give the `.box css("display","block")` function.

Please advice if anyone knows a solution for this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: in the HTML code, is the .box div inside the .clicker ?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the show()/hide() methods instead of css("display",...)?

Comment: Would be a lot easier to understand the flow, if you would post your codes?

Comment: the .box is not inside the .clicker. It seats at the bottom of the document as a separate div - position is fixed and z-index: 999 so it's floating on top of the whole page.

Comment: I don't know if  show()/hide() would behave differently

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote a new code for this example to give it to you here and realised there was no issue. I was doind something wrong in my file.

Comment: Very sorry and thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a transparent div behind the box div which will cover entire screen. If it does not work, try to be clear about jQuery event bubbling. Let me know if any of these work.